# How can I tell if a react application is a single page application?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, single-page-application

I am not certain whether to call a certain app Single Page Application (SPA) or Multi Page Application (MPA). The app utilizes react, redux, and react-router which uses a `<switch />` to route to a couple of `<Route />`s,  with each  wrapping a React component. The app looks and feels to some as traditional MPA as each page looks distinct, with one 'page' "next" to another. However, the fact of there being a single store, javascript controlling the urls, and there being a single `entry` point in webpack.config.js makes me think of it as an SPA. How is the line drawn between SPA and MPA?

Comment: It's an SPA if it uses a single html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spa is not really about how it feels, but more about how it works.

Usually, if the routing is handled by the front end, it's an spa.

Of course this is over simplifying but for modern applications it's usually true.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `react` you have to install its dependency first.

If you are using `create-react-app YourReactProject` `command` you will notice there is only one `html` generated at  `YourReactProject/public/index.html` which has only one `div` with `id = root` and your `index.js` at `YourReactProject/src/index.js` uses this `div` as the  parent `node` for the react ***by this line of code.***

`ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`

So whenever you click some `url` the `root div` will remain in the page but the new page content will become `root node`'s  children. So technically you have only one `div id=root` but its children gets replaced. Hope you got the answer.